# Moving attributes to child element using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem I can't solve. Here's a snippet of the structure of an xml I have:

```
    <body>
        <tu creationdate="01022015" creationid="author1" changedate="02022015" changeid="author2">
            <tuv xml:lang="it-IT">
                <seg>Questo è testo</seg>
            </tuv>
            <tuv xml:lang="en-GB">
                <seg>This is a test</seg>
            </tuv>
            <tuv xml:lang="de-DE">
                <seg>Das ist ein Test</seg>
            </tuv>
        </tu>
        <tu>
        </tu>
    </body>
</tmx>
```

I'd like to move all the attributes from the  element to the  child element without overwriting anything. Something like this:

```
    <body>
        <tu>
            <tuv xml:lang="it-IT" creationdate="01022015" creationid="author1" changedate="02022015" changeid="author2">
                <seg>Questo è testo</seg>
            </tuv>
            <tuv xml:lang="en-GB" creationdate="01022015" creationid="author1" changedate="02022015" changeid="author2">
                <seg>This is a test</seg>
            </tuv>
            <tuv xml:lang="de-DE" creationdate="01022015" creationid="author1" changedate="02022015" changeid="author2">
                <seg>Das ist ein Test</seg>
            </tuv>
        </tu>
        <tu>
        </tu>
    </body>
</tmx>
```

This is my best attempt so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body/tu/tuv">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately, though, this always overwrites the xml:lang attribute in the  element.
Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance

Enrico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this always overwrites the xml:lang attribute in the element.

It does not overwrite it. You simply did not include the existing attributes in your `xsl:apply-templates` instructions (though you did include `node()` twice, thus duplicating all child elements).

Also, in order to get the result you want, you must also remove the attributes from the parent `tu` element.

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tu/@*"/>

<xsl:template match="tuv">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note the use of `xsl:copy-of` to add the attributes. This is because using `xsl:apply-templates` would not do anything, after we have added the empty template matching them.

Comment: Thank you very much, It's working now! I'm quite a novice, I've just learned something new :)